# C++: glfw3 on ubuntu undefined reference

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glfw, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to compile a program from [this](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html) tutorial.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
 fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
 if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
 glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
 GLFWwindow* window;
 glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
 if (!glfwInit())
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL); 
 if (!window)
 {
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
 glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
 {
  float ratio;
  int width, height;
  glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
  ratio = width / (float) height;
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
  glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
  glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
  glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
  glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
  glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
  glEnd();
  glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  glfwPollEvents();
 }
 glfwDestroyWindow(window);
 glfwTerminate();
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

What I get when I try to compile this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformCreateCursor':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2d91): undefined reference to `XcursorImageCreate' 
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2e61): undefined reference to `XcursorImageLoadCursor'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x2e75): undefined reference to `XcursorImageDestroy'
```

I use this command

```
g++ glfw.o -lglfw3 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -lm -lalleg
```

Running on Ubuntu 13.10

I looked everywhere, installed box2d, glfw, glfw3, allegro, and some more libs - the reason is that I went through every discussion that remotely mentions glfw and undefined references, and in my frustration caused by five hours of stalemate, installed any library that was mentioned. The result remains the same. I don't know where to go from here. Any ideas what causes this please?
Thank you.

Comment: Note: without the `-c` argument, `g++` compiles AND links into an executable. If you want an actual `.o` file, use the `-c` argument. This isn't the reason you're getting the linking error though.

Comment: Are you linking against `opengl32`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Hopefully not, this is using X11/GLX on Linux. `opengl32` is for Win32/WGL on Windows.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Wrong, libraries on the left should be dependent on libraries on the right.

Comment: @Kuro, Also add `-lXcursor` to fix your dependencies.

Comment: @Andon M.Coleman: -lXcursor was the one it was missing. thank you a lot. could you please write it as an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

until mr. AndonM.Coleman posts an answer for this question ( which he did in the comment ), the problem was in missing `-lXcursor`

Answer (score 2):

Manually writing those commands out is a pain.  You want to use `pkg-config`.  Something like this (Makefile syntax):

```
LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs glfw3) -lm -lalleg
g++ $(LDFLAGS) glfw.o -pthread $(LIBS)
```

Also note use of `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.

#### Note about library order

Using GNU Binutils on Linux, the order in which you specify libraries is important.  This is not true on OS X or Windows.  Symbols are resolved by scanning libraries in order, so any unresolved symbols in a library must be resolved by a library which comes afterwards in the command line arguments.

Note that if you use static GLFW, you may need to use `pkg-config --libs --static glfw3`.

#### Terminology note

The command,

```
g++ file.o <flags>
```

does not compile code.  The code is already compiled, this command links the compiled files.

Comment: It isn't that bad, really. I switch to the terminal ( which i keep on bottom desktop [ 4 desktops ] ), press "up", and get the last command :D Besides that, I have a makefile done for the previous code which used GLUT. I'm trying to switch to GLFW3 since openGl site says not to use GLUT, and GLFW is best suited for games ( took me a while to notice ). I'll have a makefile set up later, but for now it was important to start the damn graphics mode, draw something, and not go crazy in the process.

Comment: And thank you for terminology note .) I kinda knew I was using the wrong terminology when I was writing the question, but didn't know the right one .)